# Canon Pixma MP 160 doesn't recognize ink cartridges

Tags: ink, canon-pixma, multi-function-printer

My Canon Pixma MP 160 printer/scanner/copier is not recognizing my printer cartridges. The alarm light as well as the black and color light all come on and it's like it's locked up.

Answer (score 0):

I've had it happen with another pixma where I refill ink. If you use the newer cartridges, with the chips, try cleaning the contacts on the cartridge with alcohol wipes - this happens with dirty contacts